# How to create .obb file for my android project?

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

i am creating a app and my app size 80 mb and i want to make .obb file for publishing app on play store. i tried google and also try [This](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) but not getting please give me proper way for how to create .obb file.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Write the similar code like this in command prompt and get the .obb file in tools folder>>
`C:\>C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools\jobb -d C:\
Myworkspace\ImageTargets\assets\ -o Imagetargets.obb -k globe -pn com.ib.globeap
p.activity -pv 200 -v`